# Laravel/React - Getting an array of data from controller to react component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, laravel, dom

### My case:

> I am combining **Laravel** (laravel/ui scaffolding) and **React App**.
> This is my first time trying this, and found myself stuck in getting data from BE to FE.
>
> I Looks like I am getting the data, **but my array of $testData is converted into a string When being logged from the Dataset of that element.** I am not sure what I should do to have my array back to a json format instead.

#### the code:

A Controller sending my data:

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $testData = [
            ["name" => "Lucy"],
            ["name" => "Kurt"],
            ["name" => "Emma"],
        ];

        return view('intern.index')->with('testData', $testData);
    }
```

I have my blade, loading a div with a certain **id**:

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('body')
    <div id="react-app" data-list={{ json_encode($testData) }} ></div>
@endsection
```

And my react component **app.js** that is rendered on the blade view:

```js
function App( props ) {

    console.log(props.list)

    return (
        <div className="container">
            Hello World!
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById('react-app')) {
    const thisElement = document.getElementById('react-app');
    let props = Object.assign({}, thisElement.dataset);
    console.log(props)
    /* The restult I am getting from that log:
    {
      list: "{{\"name\":\"Lucy\"},{\"name\":\"Kurt\"},{\"name\":\"Emma\"}}"
    }
    */
    ReactDOM.render(<App list={props.list} />, thisElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

The solution was to simply parse the result back.

```js
if (document.getElementById('react-app')) {
    const thisElement = document.getElementById('react-app');
    let props = Object.assign({}, thisElement.dataset);
    console.log(props)
    /* The restult I am getting from that log:
    {
      list: "{{\"name\":\"Lucy\"},{\"name\":\"Kurt\"},{\"name\":\"Emma\"}}"
    }
    */
    ReactDOM.render(<App list={JSON.parse(props.list)} />, thisElement);
}
```

Comment: You should really look at Interia.js if you're looking to use Laravel and React and want to pass data back and forth. It's really nice to work with and makes it easy!